# Representing a type hierarchy with Boost Graph Library (BGL)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I'm new to the BGL.

I'm trying to represent a type hierarchy along these lines:

```
Number : terminal(double)
String : terminal(std::string)
Vec2
    x : Number
    y : Number
Circle
    position : Vec2
    radius : Number
```

I'm using the following code:

```
struct Descriptor { std::string name; };

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, Descriptor, Descriptor> Graph;

static inline void addVertex(Graph& g, const std::string& name)
{
    Graph::vertex_descriptor d = boost::add_vertex( g );
    g[ d ].name = name;
}

static inline void addEdge(Graph& g, const std::string& name, Index source, Index target)
{
    std::pair<Graph::edge_descriptor, bool> d = boost::add_edge( source, target, g );
    g[ d.first ].name = name;
}
```

...with the idea that Vertex properties would identify the "type names" (Number, String, Vec2 and Circle) and Edge properties would identify the "member names" (x, y, position and radius) of a compound type's components.

The conceptual trouble I'm running into is that a Vertex (Vec2, for instance) can have two members with the same type. In such a model, is it ok to create separate edges for Vec2 -> Number(x) and Vec2 -> Number(y)? Is this the correct approach?

Ultimately, I would like to be able to traverse the graph such that if we started at Circle, we would visit (in order): position.x, position.y, radius.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you want a graph, and not a tree? Also, why not a custom datastructure? Are you going to run Prim's, A* or Dijkstra on it?

Comment: Was experimenting with implementing with BGL because of its many search algorithms, etc.